# Windows Server 2003 and Apache running together

Tags: apache-http-server, port-forwarding, iis

I have a windows server 2003 in my server..and the default port 80 is being served by IIS. Recently, I installed Bitnami Trac into that server, and now the trac is running on port 8080. (I gave this port as 8080 because there are some other websites already running using IIS, so that this installation won't effect them.)

Now, I added my domain, trac.my-domiain.com to the bitnami apache's trac virtual host config file using the ServerName.

So now when I hit trac.my-domiain.com it gives an error saying invalid Host name..I think its given by IIS? when I hit trac.my-domiain.com:8080, the bitnami's default page opens. So I can access my trac installation using trac.my-domiain.com:8080/trac.

But this is not what I want...I want to change this to open the /trac path when I enter trac.my-domiain.com:8080. and also, I want to access the trac.my-domiain.com without the port in the url.

Can I do this? My mind says there should be an option in IIS to rewrite the domain name to 8080 inside without showing it to the client, and hand over the task to apache...? but I don't know how to do it...

Can somebody suggest me the best way?

thanks in advance!

Comment: IIS does have a Reverse Proxy feature that allows IIS to serve as a front for another webserver operating on another computer or port, but it requires IIS7 or later and so does not work on WS2003, sorry.

Comment: Hi, Dai, tnx so much for the tip..i will accept the site with 8080 then...any idea about how to make the domain go to /trac folder?

Comment: You'd need to configure your Apache virtual host to use `/trac` as the website's root folder. I don't know Apache so I cannot help you further, but this is a common task, I suggest searching online.

Comment: Hi Dai, tnx a lot..i know that..but this one uses bitnami's trac...that's not straight forward...but got it working somehow :)

Comment: Another option is to configure your router, when forwarding port 80, to remap it to port 8080. Most routers support this fuctionality.